# Solve $\lim_{x\to -\infty }\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to -\infty }\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x} = \frac12\lim_{x\to -\infty }\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x} = \frac12\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{-1}{x}+\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x}\right)=\frac12\left(0+\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x}\right) = \frac12\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+4x^2}{x^2}} = \frac12\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}+4}=\frac22=1$

But the graph of the function is clearly approaching $-1$ when $x$ is large and negative. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: $x \ne \sqrt {x^2}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| $ and as $x$ is negative $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ so $\frac {\sqrt{1+4x^2}}x = \frac {\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{-\sqrt{x^2}} = -\sqrt{\frac {1+4x^2}{x^2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \ne \sqrt {x^2}$.

$|x| =\sqrt{x^2}$ so $x = \begin{cases}\sqrt{x^2}& x\ge 0\\-\sqrt{x^2}& x < 0\end{cases}$.

And as we are taking $x \to -\infty$ we know $x < 0$.

So

$\lim_{x\to -\infty }\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x} = \frac12\lim_{x\to -\infty }\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x} = \frac12\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{-1}{x}+\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x}\right)=\frac12\left(0+\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x}\right) = \color{red}{\frac12\left(0+\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{-\sqrt{x^2}}\right)}=\frac12\lim_{x\to -\infty}\color{red}-\sqrt{\frac{1+4x^2}{x^2}} = \frac12\lim_{x\to -\infty}\color{red}-\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}+4}=\color{red}{\frac 12(\color{green}- 2)}=\color{red}-\frac22=\color{red}-1$

Answer (score 2):

You can not put $x$ under the square since it is negative. You can put $-x$:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x} = -\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+4x^2}{(-x)^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x = sign(x)\sqrt{x^{2}}$ we have:

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x} = -\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+4x^2}{x^2}}$$

Since $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2}} = 0$$

and $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{4x^{2}}{x^{2}} = 4$$

then $$0+4 = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{4x^{2}}{x^{2}} + \frac{1}{x^{2}} = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{4x^{2}+1}{x^{2}}$$

Since $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous in a neighborhood of 4,

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+4x^2}{x^2}} = \sqrt{\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{4x^{2}+1}{x^{2}}} = \sqrt{4} = 2.$$

So $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{x} = -2$$

$$\frac{1}{2}(-2) = -1$$

Just like it shows on that graph.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\sqrt{1+4x^2}=\sqrt{x^2(4+\frac{1}{x^2})}$$

$$=|x|\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

$$=\color{red}{-}x\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

because, near $ -\infty $,  $|x|=-x$.